# Launch Error in Expression Blend 2

Tags: silverlight

I get an exception error when I F5/Build any Silverlight project within Expression Blend 2:

Launch Error

```
Could not start ""
due to the following error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The 
system cannot find the file specified
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo 
startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Microsoft.Expression.Project.ExecutableProjectBase.Execυte()
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling seems to suggest it can be an incorrectly configured dev server.

Here's a [Blend Configurator](http://blogs.msdn.com/expression/archive/2007/05/29/working-with-visual-studio-code-name-orcas-and-expression-blend.aspx)

Here's [the post that let me to it](http://silverlight.net/forums/p/2628/7054.aspx)

If this doesn't help try the following:

1. Remove the Silverlight project reference in your web app's properties pages, rebuild, add it again.
2. Ensure the virtual directory or other path your web app is running under (Project URL:  http://localhost/mysilverlightapp for example) actually gets you to it. Hit 'Create Virtual Directory' if not. See if it does now.
3. Check that your page with the silverlight control has the correct file name for your Silverlight dll.